# No package found: install xclip in RHEL 7.6

Tags: rhel, package-management, xclip

I am new to the RHEL and want to install `xclip` package.

I have tried

```
yum install xclip
```

It returned

```
no package xclip
```

Comment: Which version of RHEL are you using? Do you have a valid subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install/configure the EPEL repository (see: [Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)) and install via `yum check-update ; yum install xclip`